# Find the Scalar Invariant under a Lorentz-transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, invariants

**[Question]**
Given the components of two vector fields, $u^\alpha$, $v^\beta$, show that $u^\alpha v^\alpha = u^0 v^0 + u^1 v^1 + u^2 v^2 + u^3 v^3$ is not a scalar invariant under a Lorentz-transformation.

Source(s): None - (Professor's Handout)

**My Attempted Solution**

Here is my attempted solution. In short, for the problem, I just need to show - using a single counterexample - that the provided quantity in the question is not invariant. Therefore, I don't need to prove that the quantity is never the same in a different reference frame since there may oftentimes be special cases where they are the same. But with that said, I do feel like I am really overcomplicating my answer to the question as shown below. Any clear help and guidance will be much appreciated to help me arrive at a clear and correct answer. Thank you all for your time and assistance!

---

To make $u^\alpha v^\alpha$ invariant - that is, to create a counterexample to the given problem - the following equation below should be able to show $u^\alpha v^\alpha$ 's invariance.
$$\begin{pmatrix} u^0 & u^1 & u^2 & u^3\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & +1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & +1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & +1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} v^0 \\ v^1 \\ v^2 \\ v^3\end{pmatrix}$$

Furthermore, this same idea can be applied to another reference frame (say, $u^{\alpha '} v^{\alpha '}$) - and thus proving that the counterexample equation *(not the originally provided equation in the question)* $u^\alpha v^\alpha = -u^0 v^0 + u^1 v^1 + u^2 v^2 + u^3 v^3$ is indeed invariant:
$$\begin{pmatrix} u^{0'} & u^{1'} & u^{2'} & u^{3'}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & +1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & +1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & +1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} v^{0'} \\ v^{1'} \\ v^{2'} \\ v^{3'}\end{pmatrix}$$

However, note that since the shown equation in the original question does not have the negative sign before $u^0 v^0$ seen above, one can thus not use $\eta$ - that is the below matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & +1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & +1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & +1 \end{pmatrix} $$

for this: $u^\alpha v^\alpha = u^0 v^0 + u^1 v^1 + u^2 v^2 + u^3 v^3$ 
Rather than $\eta$, our equation right above will simply have the matrix identity operator $\delta$ used instead.

But, despite "knowing" all this, I am nevertheless confronted with the same question - how can I prove that the question's equation is not a scalar invariant *under a Lorentz-transformation*? Or, would my counterexample to disapprove the question's equation being invariant suffice?

As said before, I really feel like I am overcomplicating the question and my solution. However, if I am in the right direction or if I should try other approaches, I would greatly appreciate any clear guidance. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: What you are saying is that the proposed scalar product is not the usual invariant product, which is true, but that in itself doesn't show that it is not invariant. You just need to come up with the simplest Lorentz transformation you can think of and apply it to the vectors.

Comment: @Javier, thank you for replying! Currently, the simplest Lorentz transformation I can think of is the 1D Lorentz transformation shown below:

$$t' = \gamma (t- \frac{vx}{c^2}), x' = \gamma (x -vt)$$

However, how do I go about applying it to the vectors for the original equation and question I have? Do I simply substitute for $t$ and $x$ using $u^0 v^0$ and $u^1 v^1$ respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lorentz invariant mean:

$$\vec{v}\cdot \vec{u}=\vec{v}'\cdot\vec{u}'\tag 1$$

with

$\vec{v}'=L\,\vec{v}$

and

$\vec{u}'=L\,\vec{u}$

where L is the Lorentz transformation

you get

$$\vec{v}^T \vec{u}=\vec{v}^T\,L^T\,L\,\vec{u}$$

thus

$$\vec{v}\cdot \vec{u}\ne\vec{v}'\cdot\vec{u}'$$

**Edit**

[image]

Lorentz transformation matrix :

$$L=\begin{bmatrix}
  \gamma(w_x) & -w_x/c\,\gamma(w_x) & 0 & 0 \\
 -w_x/c\,\gamma(w_x) & \gamma(w_x) & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

with:

$\gamma(v)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{w_x^2}{c^2}}}$

$$L^T\,L= \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} {\frac {{{\it \gamma(w_x)}}^{2} \left( {c}^{2}+{w_x}
^{2} \right) }{{c}^{2}}}&-2\,{\frac {{{\it \gamma(w_x)}}^{2}w_x}{c}}&0&0
\\  -2\,{\frac {{{\it \gamma(w_x)}}^{2}w_x}{c}}&{\frac {{{\it \gamma(w_x)
}}^{2} \left( {c}^{2}+{w_x}^{2} \right) }{{c}^{2}}}&0&0
\\  0&0&1&0\\  0&0&0&1\end {array}
 \right]
$$

where $w_x$ is a constant velocity between the coordinate systems S and S'

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, @Eli! This was great and easy to understand. However, just a quick question if you have the time and don't mind it - while I understand that $v^\alpha$ can be expanded like this in vector form: $$\begin{pmatrix} v^0 \\ v^1 \\ v^2 \\v^3 \end{pmatrix}$$

And $v^{\alpha^T}$ can be expanded as well like below:
$$\begin{pmatrix} v^0 & v^1 & v^2 & v^3 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: How can one exactly expand the $L$ (i.e. Lorentz transformation) you have written in the answer above in matrix form?
Perhaps something like this?
$$\begin{pmatrix} A & B & 0 & 0 \\ C & D & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

I would sincerely appreciate any clarification. Thank you! Of course, if I wrote anything odd or incorrect here, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @Athenian I will write you the questions in my answer

Comment: thank you very much for answering the question clearly and concisely! I really appreciate it! I've upvoted your answer and it'll show once I acquire enough reputation. Once again, thank you for your help!

Comment: More of an after-thought, but should the standalone $v$'s (i.e. not the ones "in" $\gamma$) in your Lorentz transformation be $\beta$ instead? Or is there a good reason to omit the $c$ in $\beta$ to produce only $v$? I would sincerely appreciate any clarifications. Thank you!

Comment: @Athenian you are right, my mistake

Comment: Great! Thanks for the confirmation and correction! 

Comment: I noticed your recent edit and thank you very much for adding the extra bit of information!
Quick question from me though, when I write $\vec{u^\alpha}' = L\vec{u^\alpha}$, is it alright if I interpret that $L$ in this equation as the below matrix? Or is it incorrect for me to write $L$ in this way? Rather, I should simply stick with $(v)$ instead ...

$$L = \begin{bmatrix} \gamma (u^\alpha) & -\frac{u^\alpha}{c} \gamma (u^\alpha) & 0 & 0 \\ -\frac{u^\alpha}{c} \gamma (u^\alpha) & \gamma (u^\alpha) & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @Athenian no this is not correct, I will add a figure to make it clear

Comment: Great! I now understand. Essentially, the Lorentz transformation could otherwise be stated as a Lorentz boost in the $x$ direction with speed (in this case) $w$, right? And both vectors in $\vec{v^\alpha}' = L\vec{v^\alpha}$ and $\vec{u^\alpha}' = L\vec{u^\alpha}$ use the exact same $L$ ...
Thank you so much for providing the figure. It was incredibly helpful!

Comment: An additional question, in your edit, I noticed that you erased the latter $\eta$ portion of your answer in $\vec{v}^T \vec{u} = \vec{v}^T L^T L \vec{u}$. While I can confirm that this recent edit is indeed correct, how exactly does $L^T$ and $L$ pop up in the right side of your equation? Shouldn't both sides of the equation be equal to each other? I would sincerely appreciate it if you could please clarify. Thank you!

Comment: you can check by matrices multiplication that $L\,\eta\,L=\eta$ this is why the line element $x_\mu\,x^\mu=x'_\mu\,x'^\mu$ with $x'^\mu=L\,\begin{bmatrix}
   x^0 \\
   x^i \\
 \end{bmatrix}$ and $x'_\mu=\eta\,L\,\begin{bmatrix}
   x^0 \\
   x^i \\
 \end{bmatrix}$  but $L^T\,L$ is not $\eta$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and I apologize for my moment of confusion. However, to be sure, $\vec{v}^T \vec{u} = \vec{v}^T L^T L \vec{u}$ is actually supposed to be $\vec{v'}^T \vec{u'} = \vec{v}^T L^T L \vec{u}$ if I am to be picky about the notations, right?